# Google spreadsheet API, unable to send mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

```
if( row.toString() =="Others")   {

 sheet.msgBox("success");
   MailApp.sendEmail("xyz@abc.com","hi","hi");


    }
    else
      sheet.msgBox("no");
```

using the above code i have been able to get a success alert, but im not able to send the mail
, help required

Comment: Some more information is required to answer this question.

Comment: i am using the onEdit trigger, while i edit a cell in the spreadsheet i am able to get the alert "success", but not able to shoot email for the  same event

Comment: Are there any errors? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails shows that MailApp.sendEmail("email, "subject", "message"); should work

Comment: i know i have referred to the API, i have also set a 'Execution failure notification' to send mail on my email-id in case of a exception/error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onEdit runs as the person editing the spreadsheet. ie. with the rights of the person editing the spreadsheet. And so would be unable to send an email.

```
  Google Calendar, Gmail, and Sites are not anonymous and the simple triggers cannot access those services.
```

See Understanding Triggers, here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers

Work around:
I think you can use UrlFetchApp.fetch and so you could create a web app as a workaround. i.e. call the web app using UrlFetchApp.fetch and have the web app send the email.

Answer (score 2):

Dont  name it onEdit, instead install it as a regular trigger. Then it runs with Owner permissions. However there are some restrictions of code from such triggers.

Comment: Looks like you are right: "Unlike the simple trigger onEdit, the installable trigger can act as the user who installed the trigger." https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers